# How to remove the redundant ContourLabels

Tags: plotting, labeling

```
ContourPlot[
 EuclideanDistance[{-5, 0}, {x, y}]*
  EuclideanDistance[{5, 0}, {x, y}], {x, -15, 15}, {y, -11, 11}, 
 Contours -> Range[5, 150, 20], Frame -> False, 
 ContourLabels -> (Text[Style[#3, Directive[Blue, 15]], {#1, #2}] &), 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
 ColorFunction -> (If[# < 145, 
     ColorData[{"TemperatureMap", {0, 145}}, #], None] &), 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]

How to remove those redundant `25`? I just hope to keep one or two. But I get a ton of label `25`, which makes the graphic look crowded...

Comment: adding the option `MaxRecursion -> 1` seems to get rid of multiple labels.

Comment: `PlotPoints -> 75` reduces the `25` labels to three widely-separated labels and provides a smooth plot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simplifying and evaluating the argument will also reduce the redundant labels.

```
$Version

(* "13.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 3, 2021)" *)

ContourPlot[
 Evaluate[
  Simplify[
   EuclideanDistance[{-5, 0}, {x, y}]*
    EuclideanDistance[{5, 0}, {x, y}]]],
 {x, -15, 15}, {y, -11, 11},
 Contours -> Range[5, 150, 20],
 Frame -> False,
 ContourLabels ->
  (Text[Style[#3, Directive[Blue, 15]], {#1, #2}] &),
 AspectRatio -> Automatic,
 ColorFunction ->
  (If[# < 145, ColorData[{"TemperatureMap", {0, 145}}, #], 
     None] &),
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

```
cp = ContourPlot[EuclideanDistance[{-5, 0}, {x, y}] EuclideanDistance[{5, 0}, {x, y}], 
  {x, -15, 15}, {y, -11, 11}, 
  Contours -> Range[5, 150, 20], Frame -> False, 
  ContourLabels -> (Text[Style[#3, Directive[Blue, 15]], {#1, #2}] &),
  AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
  ColorFunction -> (If[# < 145, ColorData[{"TemperatureMap", {0, 145}}, #], None] &), 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]

You can post-process `cp` to remove duplicate labels:

```
ReplaceAll[labels : {__Text} :> DeleteDuplicatesBy[First] @ labels] @ cp
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can add the option

```
DisplayFunction -> ReplaceAll[labels : {__Text} :> DeleteDuplicatesBy[First] @ labels]
```

to `ContourPlot[...]` to get the same picture.

Comment: Thanks very much

Answer (score 3):

Follow the approach by @Bob Hanlon.

I think the problem come from the  Complex Function `EuclideanDistance` since it contain `Sqrt` and `Abs`.

```
EuclideanDistance[{a, b}, {x, y}]
(* Sqrt[Abs[a - x]^2 + Abs[b - y]^2] *)
```

So sometimes I avoid to use `EuclideanDistance` or `Norm`. Here we can use `#.#&` instead.

```
Sqrt[# . # &[{-5, 0} - {x, y}] # . # &[{5, 0} - {x, y}]]
```

Or

```
Sqrt[Norm[{-5, 0} - {x, y}]^2 Norm[{5, 0} - {x, y}]^2]
```

Or

```
Sqrt[EuclideanDistance[{-5, 0}, {x, y}]^2 EuclideanDistance[{5, 
   0}, {x, y}]^2]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot...